# Missing a part from a plug for a DC car charger, don't know where to find it

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, automotive

I am in a predicament, I need to replace the part highlighted in blue but don't know what it's called or where to get it. The black nut holds everything inside, and it came loose so everything fell out in my car. I recovered the fuse and the black nut but not the circled part which connects the fuse to the car's outlet, it is the cylindrical contact at the end of every car plug. The contact I have here is salvaged from another plug, and it works for a few seconds but then the device loses power. So I think this contact is the wrong size or maybe I'm missing another piece? Any idea where to get a different one, or quick hacks to make better contact?

This is for a dashcam.

[image: exploded car charging plug]

[image: DC car plug]

Comment: Did you also lose the spring which goes in before the fuse?

Comment: ...and removing panels on my car console yesterday, I just found one of those from when my USB charger imploded on me (and I was unable to reassemble it at the time, because the part had fallen into the console).

Comment: Brhans I don't think so, there's an embedded spring inside the housing. When I put the fuse in I can bounce it. When putting it all together you have to press the fuse down to screw the nut on. So I think it makes contact.

Comment: make a new contact from a copper bolt ... some hardware stores sell them

Comment: Damn great idea thanks. I could also use that for another plug I have that works but has spotty contact.

Answer (score 1):

So it is often called a nipple but also I suggest that you are missing a spring to make sure all stays in contact.

Two choices:

1. make one - or rip one from another device,

or

2. buy a complete replacement.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't see anywhere I can order a nipple or any other part besides a fuse or the whole charger. The spring is embedded inside the housing, the nipple springs against the fuse when put together. Is it possible and relatively easy to replace the whole charger with a usb plug?